# Fatal signal 11 with a sql union query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting the following error without a stack trace when running a union query

```
07-09 18:04:39.957: A/libc(5248): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x3f800002 (code=1), thread 5264 (AsyncTask #1)
```

The query i am running looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2) WHERE col1=1 ORDER BY col2 DESC
```

My best guess is that sql is crashing, atleast when i step with the debugger it crashes on the query and changing my sql to

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Also stops it from chrashing

Comment: are you sure the inner query returns an acceptable phrase for the `FROM` operator? Maybe just try executing the inner query and see what /if it runs

Comment: My SQL is kinda rusty, but have you tried removing the first "SELECT * FROM"? Your subquery returns a list of rows, not a table, so I think you can't access it using a SELECT.

Try this: 

    (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2) WHERE col1=1 ORDER BY col2 DESC;

Comment: The thing is that the query sometimes works and sometimes doesn't .. It might have something to do with what @Scott said that on of the inner queries fails.